# Merge / Join data.tables per row

Tags: r, join, merge, data.table, rows

I have the following data tables and I would like to make a single data table out of all three.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)

dt.Ger <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 365),
                     Germany = rnorm(365, 2, 1), check.names = FALSE)
dt.Aut <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 365),
                     Austria = rnorm(365, 4, 2), check.names = FALSE)
dt.Den <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 365),
                     Denmark = rnorm(365, 3, 1), check.names = FALSE)

dt.Ger <- dt.Ger %>%
  mutate(month = format(date, '%b'), 
         date = format(date, '%d')) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = Germany)

dt.Aut <- dt.Aut %>%
  mutate(month = format(date, '%b'), 
         date = format(date, '%d')) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = Austria)

dt.Den <- dt.Den %>%
  mutate(month = format(date, '%b'), 
         date = format(date, '%d')) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = Denmark)
```

Now I would like to link all tables together, i.e. first `dt.Ger`, then possibly add two empty lines and then append `dt.Aut`, now add again two empty lines and finally add `dt.Den`. Ideally, it would be great if Germany were the first headline, then Austria (in the second empty line before `dt.Aut`) and then Denmark (in the second empty line before `dt.Den`).

So that I only have a single table as a return. This table should look something like this (I only did it with SnippingTool, so it only serves to explain):

[image]

**EDIT:**
Using

```
l <- list(dt.Ger, dt.Aut, dt.Den)
l.result <- rbindlist(l)
```

yields to:

[image]

And I want to get an extra space/line/row (at the red parts) where Germany, Austria and Denmark is written.

Comment: I'm not really sure where this is going. Looks like three separate tables to me? Do you want to merge them in the `data.table` structure (see `?rbindlist`) or output them as HTML `datatables`?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you want to achieve here aswell, but one option I can think of (depending on the aim ot this) is to create a column "Country" and populate for each table. Then use `bind_rows()` to merge them all together

Comment: why not just use lapply and have them as sublists? if you really want them as data.frames you could use sapply. thes should also work for you plot_ly functions

Comment: @ismirsehregal I can merge/join all 3 data tables with ```rbindlist()``` now, but how can I add a title/header or and empty row (with an header/title) before each new data table? I have to output one data table in RShiny, so all 3 data tables have to be merge before.

Comment: @D.J thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure what I should use here for ```FUN```???

Comment: @ismirsehregal I have edited my question depending on using ```rbindlist()```

Comment: i am not sure which step you mean. my solution was exactly how you edited your question `l <- list(dt.Ger, dt.Aut, dt.Den)` . with lapply you can then access every country as like a data.frame. can you explain why you need it as single data.frame?  as list of lists you can access every singe sublist instead of meshing it all into one df with empty rows between countries. but it seems i missed your actual goal. @ismirsehregal seems to have found a good way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure, what you are trying to achive - for me it seems you are better of working with a list of data.tables.

Furthermore, I switched to using `dcast` instead of `pivot_wider` so you can drop `tidyr` / `dplyr`.

However, here is an approach inserting `NA`s inbetween the different data.tables using `rbindlist`:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)

dt.Ger <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 365),
                     Germany = rnorm(365, 2, 1), check.names = FALSE)
dt.Aut <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 365),
                     Austria = rnorm(365, 4, 2), check.names = FALSE)
dt.Den <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 365),
                     Denmark = rnorm(365, 3, 1), check.names = FALSE)

# or rather date  ~ month?
dt.Ger[, c("month", "date") := list(format(date, '%b'), format(date, '%d'))]
dt.Ger <- dcast(dt.Ger, month ~ date, value.var = "Germany")

dt.Aut[, c("month", "date") := list(format(date, '%b'), format(date, '%d'))]
dt.Aut <- dcast(dt.Aut, month ~ date, value.var = "Austria")

dt.Den[, c("month", "date") := list(format(date, '%b'), format(date, '%d'))]
dt.Den <- dcast(dt.Den, month ~ date, value.var = "Denmark")

# use a list of data.tables:
recommended <- list(Germany = dt.Ger, Austria = dt.Aut, Denmark = dt.Den)

DT <- rbindlist(list(data.table(month = c("", "Germany")), dt.Ger, data.table(month = c("", "Austria")), dt.Aut, data.table(month = c("", "Denmark")), dt.Den), fill = TRUE) # [, V1 := NULL]
DT[,(names(DT)):= lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = names(DT)]
for (j in seq_len(ncol(DT))){
  set(DT, which(is.na(DT[[j]])), j, "")
}

print(DT)
```

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what I want. Just one further question. Now the empty cells have NA-values. If I print this in RShiny as an output then I don't want to see there NA-values.. The should be just empty cells. Is this possible?

Comment: Currently the majority of your columns is `numeric`. You would need to change the column type to `character` to pass e.g. an empty string ("").

Comment: Would it be possible to change only these rows to  ```character```?

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible. `data.table`s have column classes.

Comment: I don't know your usecase, but I'd really recommend workind with lists of `data.table`s instead of inserting header information in a single `data.table` object.

Comment: If I switch to ```list``` and don't use a ```data table``` anymore, then I'm not sure if I can gives this as a "data table"-output in ```RShiny```?? Besides, I don't really know about ```lists``` in R.

Comment: The list will hold 3 `data.table` objects and you can use it in `shiny` just fine. However, please see my edit regarding the conversion `as.character`.

Comment: You are welcome! However, please try to research on the list approach - it will make things much easier for you on the long run. Cheers